# How to remove Linux installation and install a new flavour, while keeping Windows intact

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, multi-boot, grub

I dual-boot Ubuntu with Windows 10. I wish to remove Ubuntu and install Manjaro while keeping Windows intact (thus not having to re-install it).

Where do I start?

- Do I just wipe the Ubuntu partition and install Manjaro from USB?
- Will GRUB work right away?
- Can this be done without wiping the disk completely?

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, have you considered utilizing a free hypervisor within Windows 10 (like VirtualBox or the built-in Hyper-V) to run Linux as a virtual machine?  Quite frankly, we see a **lot** of questions within the Super User realm posted by people who encounter problems while they dual-boot Windows and Linux.  Just something to consider.

Comment: There are reasons why I dual boot and not virtualize.

Comment: Fair enough.  I'm sure that one of our dual-boot gurus will be able to chime in and help you out!

Answer (score 0):

Your mentioned method WILL work. But a few things to note:

If the system is EFI (especially with Windows) DO NOT reformat `/boot/efi` or Windows will require a `/bcdedit fixmbr` from a rescue disk /install media or reinstall).

If there are any  nfs or other shared partitions between Windows and Ubuntu I highly recommend NOT formatting them either OR immediately once you boot into Ubuntu post install reboot into windows and re-check your mappings.

if /boot and /or /boot/efi (if applicable, in the later case) are properly mounted grub will work properly immediately, one way to check is to open a terminal when the installer is running thru that part of install ( at the end ) and look for a 'Found Windows 10 loader on /dev/sdXY'

Where /dev/sdXY will be something like /dev/sda4

Assuming you have parts of the Ubuntu install like /home you rather not nuke and have to re-configure   just MOUNT ONLY ( do NOT reformat said partitions) If using standard partitions or /home residing inside of / and not a separate partition it is HIGHLY recommended to first back up that/those partitions before anything re-install related is started.